# Python dictionary matching words

Tags: python, dictionary

I was given a question as follows

"Standard input consists of a sequence of words, one per line.
Write a Python script named fruit.py which outputs only those words which are fruits.There are only five fruits: apple, pair, orange, banana and cherry." e.g. if standard input was "dog cat apple snake cherry" standard output would be "apple cherry". I've been having difficulty with dictionaries for some time now so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import sys

fruit = {
   "apple": True,
   "pair": True,
   "orange": True,
   "banana": True,
   "cherry": True,
}

n = sys.stdin.readlines()

i = 0
while i < len(n):
   if n[i] in fruit:
      fruit[n[i]] = False
      sys.stdout.write() (n[i])
   i = i + 1
```

Comment: What's your problem with the code you provided?

Comment: isnt this a codecademy question?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a dictionary in your case, a simple list is enough:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'pair', 'orange', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

Now, you can check if an item is in this list like below:

```
if item in fruits:
    # do something!
```

In your case, what you can do is:

```
for item in n:
   if item in fruits:
      sys.stdout.write(n)
```

Comment: A `set` would be better

Comment: For a list of 5 elements it is not required to use `set` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a set or list to store the fruits but having a dictionary is the correct choice when the list of fruits is really long, in terms of time complexity. The code for this would be

```
import sys

fruit = {
   "apple": True,
   "pair": True,
   "orange": True,
   "banana": True,
   "cherry": True,
}

n = sys.stdin.readlines()

i = 0
while i < len(n):
   if fruit[n[i]]:
      sys.stdout.write() (n[i])
   i = i + 1
```

Of course there are a lot of efficient ways to do that, but I am just giving the answer with the most minimal changes to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> fruits = ["apple", "pair", "orange", "banana", "cherry"]
>>> n = input("Enter statement :")
Enter statement :dog cat apple snake cherry
>>> n_list = n.split()
>>> for i in n_list:
    if i in fruits:
        fruits_found.append(i)


>>> fruits_found
['apple', 'cherry']
>>> " ".join(fruits_found)
'apple cherry'
```